# How can I use regexextract function in Google Docs spreadsheets to get "all" occurrences of a string?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

My text string is in cell D2:

```
Decision, ERC Case No. 2009-094 MC, In the Matter of the Application for Authority to Secure Loan from the National Electrification Administration (NEA), with Prayer for Issuance of Provisional Authority, Dinagat Island Electric Cooperative, Inc. (DIELCO) applicant(12/29/2011)
```

This function:

```
=regexextract(D2,"\([A-Z]*\)")
```

will grab (NEA) but not (DIELCO)

I would like it to extract both (NEA) and (DIELCO)

Comment: I think http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ is the recommended place for Google Docs usage questions.

Answer (score 14):

You can use capture groups, which will cause `regexextract()` to return an array. You can use this as the cell result, in which case you will get a range of results, or you can feed the array to another function to reformat it to your purpose. For example:

```
regexextract( "abracadabra" ; "(bra).*(bra)" )
```

will return the array:

```
{bra,bra}
```

Another approach would be to use `regexreplace()`. This has the advantage that the replace is global (like `s/pattern/replacement/g`), so you do not need to know the number of results in advance. For example:

```
regexreplace( "aBRAcadaBRA" ; "[a-z]+" ; "..." )
```

will return the string:

```
...BRA...BRA
```

Comment: Boom! Option 1 did what I needed, perfectly. Thanks, MetaEd

Comment: Ooops. Actually, I need to study this a bit. The solution works if there are multiple matches; it returns all of them. But if there is one and only one match, it returns none.

Comment: That is a matter of coming up with the regex that best suits your purpose. "Option 1" has two capture groups and works with strings that have two occurrences. If the number of occurrences is unknown, consider "Option 2".

Comment: so with regexextract still no way to pull out more than one match, without multiple capture groups?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two solutions, one using the specific terms in the author's example, the other one expanding on the author's sample regex pattern which appears to match all ALLCAPS terms. I'm not sure which is wanted, so I gave both.

(Put the block of text in A1)

### Generic solution for all words in ALLCAPS

```
=regexreplace(regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b\w[^A-Z]*\b","|"),"\W+","|"),"^\||\|$","")
```

Result:

```
ERC|MC|NEA|DIELCO
```

NB: The brunt of the work is in the CAPITALIZED formula, the lowercase functions are just for cleanup.

If you want space separation, the formula is a little simpler:

```
=trim(regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b\w[^A-Z]*\b"," "),"\W+"," "))
```

Result:

```
ERC MC NEA DIELCO
```

(One way I like playing with regex in google spreadsheets is to read the regex pattern from another cell so I can change it without having to edit or re-paste into all the cells using that pattern. This looks so:

Cell A1:

```
Block of text
```

Cell B1 (no quote marks):

```
\b\w[^A-Z]*\b
```

Formula, in any cell:

```
=trim(regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(A1,B$1," "),"\W+"," "))
```

By anchoring it to B$1, I can fill all my rows at once and the reference won't increment.)

---

Previous answer:

### Specific solution for selected terms (ERC, DIELCO)

```
=regexreplace(join("|",IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"ERC"),"ERC",""),IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"DIELCO"),"DIELCO","")),"(^\||\|$)","")
```

Result:

```
ERC|DIELCO
```

As before, the brunt of the work is in the CAPITALIZED formula, the lowercase functions are just for cleanup.

This formula will find any ERC or DIELCO, or both in the block of text. The initial order doesn't matter, but the output will always be ERC followed by DIELCO (the order of appearance is lost). This fixes the shortcoming with the previous answer using "(bra).*(bra)" in that isolated ERC or DIELCO can still be matched.

This also has a simpler form with space separation:

```
=trim(join(" ",IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"ERC"),"ERC",""),IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"DIELCO"),"DIELCO","")))
```

Result:

```
ERC DIELCO
```

Comment: I realize I totally missed critical details in the original question and have reworked my answer. My final, generic solution is this: `=JOIN(", ",SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE($A$1,"(^.*?\(|\).*?\(|\).*?$)","|"),"[^A-Z]+","|"),"|"))` which gives this result: **NEA, DIELCO**. It works by first removing everything that is not surrounded by parentheses: (first regex = **|NEA|DIELCO|12/29/2011|**), then removing everything that's not ALLCAPS words: (second regex = **|NEA|DIELCO|**), and finally splitting and rejoining for nice formatting. Google sheet here: https://goo.gl/3nJcFe

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SPLIT(regexreplace(A1 ; "(?s)(.)?\(([A-Z]+)\)|(.)" ; "$2");"")
```

or

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\Q"&REGEXREPLACE(A1;"\([A-Z]+\)";"\\E(.*)\\Q")&"\E")
```